# Simple login with Jsoup not working

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to do a simple login to a website and at the end I print out the title to check if it's logged in, however for some reason I keep getting the title of the login screen.

```
Response res = Jsoup
        .connect("http://moj.tvz.hr")
        .data("login", "gost", "passwd", "gost")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

Document subjectPage = Jsoup.connect("https://moj.tvz.hr")
        .cookies(cookies)
        .get();

String subjectTitle = subjectPage.title();
System.out.println("##### Printing webpage title #####\n" + subjectTitle + "\n");
```

Testing login on the actual website works just fine with the user/pw combination, so I assume something is wrong with the rest of the code, but I can't seem to find what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine what data are send with a form request, for example with browser debugging tool you will find out, that for this site there is additional parameter TVZ. It is generated for your initial request. You have to parse it out and then add to login form request.

When you are connecting to other pages you have to add TVZ as a parameter to your request. Also you have to use cookies from initial request, because login response does not return any. 
See code below.

```
        Response initResponse = Jsoup.connect("http://moj.tvz.hr").execute();
        Document doc = initResponse.parse();
        String tvz = doc.select("input[name=TVZ]").attr("value");
        Map<String, String> cookies = initResponse.cookies();

        Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://moj.tvz.hr").data("login", "gost", "passwd", "gost")//
                .data("TVZ", tvz)//
                .cookies(cookies)//
                .method(Method.POST).execute();
        System.out.println("##### Printing webpage title #####\n" + res.parse().title() + "\n");

        Document subjectPage = Jsoup.connect("https://moj.tvz.hr").data("TVZ", tvz).cookies(cookies).get();

        String subjectTitle = subjectPage.title();
        System.out.println("##### Printing webpage title #####\n" + subjectTitle + "\n");
```